# How to vertically-align media-body content in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like `media-body` content to be vertically aligned 'middle'.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    I'd like this text to be vertically aligned 'middle'
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
.media-body {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122430

**HTML**:

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="" href="#">
    <img class="media-object custom-media" src="..." alt="..." height="500px" width="500px">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    I'd like this text to be vertically aligned 'middle'
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.custom-media, .media-body{
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Does this align middle the `media-object` as well? I just need the `media-body` content vertically aligned middle

Comment: @henrywright, in the bootply, you can see the media-body aligned at middle right of the media-object.

Answer (score 9):

Since Bootstrap v3.3.0, it's possible to vertically align both the `media-object` and the `media-body`, by adding the CSS class `media-middle`.

For example:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left media-middle">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body media-middle">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

Incidentally, the docs currently don't make it clear that this works for the `media-body` as well. It does, because all `media-middle` does is to add a `vertical-align: middle;` style to an element, and `media-body` already has the style `display: table-cell` (as does `media-left` and `media-right`).

Comment: hmm, `media-middle` doesnt work for me for `media-body`. The text still stays at the top

Comment: For Bootstrap V4+, it's `align-self-center`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding this bootstrap classes

```
class="text-center"
class="pagination-centered"
```

Comment: will that align the content horizontally? I'm looking to align vertically

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ here is a post which might help you!