# Bootstrap 4 Beta align media-body text to middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to align the `media-body` text to `middle` in regards with image but i could not figure out how to do it with new `Bootstrap 4 beta` version.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451183/how-to-vertically-align-media-body-content-in-twitter-bootstrap) but it did not work with new version.

I have also tried using `text-center`,`align-middle` but that did not work either.

There was a class `media-middle` in `V3.3.7` but its not working in `v4 beta`.

Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqbybo3t/). If someone could help me it would be great.

Following is my code for `media list`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-6">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="media mb-2">
          <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body pagination-centered">
            <h6>No commission on refunds or event cancellation</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `media-middle`, which is renamed to `align-middle` in ver. 4, sets `vertical-align: middle`, which doesn't work on flex items.

For flex row items, use `align-self-center` on the `media-body` element, which does similar as `align-middle` does for i.e an inline block element.

The reason is that its parent, the `media` element, has `align-items: flex-start` (top align flex row items), hence the property:value `align-self: center` on the text will center it vertically.

*Note, the `h6` element has a default margin which offset it a little vertically, and to fix that you could either use the built in `m-0` class, or create a rule of your own `.media-body h6 { margin: 0; }`*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqbybo3t/1/)

Stack snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-6">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="media mb-2">
          <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body pagination-centered align-self-center">
            <h6>No commission on refunds or event cancellation</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body align-self-center">
            <h6>Sell tickets</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2 ">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body align-self-center">
            <h6>Book camping/Stables</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Or you can of course also use the flex container class `align-items-center` on the `media` element,
 [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqbybo3t/2/), and which to use one depends on how the other flex items should behave.*

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix might be to add the classes `d-flex` and `align-items-center` to each of your `li` and to each of your `<div class="media-body">`.

In *flexbox* terms you can add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `li` and `li > div`. See demo below and [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jckdwrLt/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-6">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body pagination-centered  d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>No commission on refunds or event cancellation</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center" style="height:64px;">
            <h6>Sell tickets</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>Book camping/Stables</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-6">
      <ul class="list-group ">
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>Discounted prices for club members</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>Live scoring with JJD and Jumpscore</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="media mb-2 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img class="mr-3  rounded-circle" width="64" height="64" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64/">
          <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>Live editing during the show</h6>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add `display:inline-block` for the `<li>` element and use `class="text-center`" for centering images. Then you should also use `class="text-center"` in media-body.